# Sticky navbar that starts on second page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to make a sticky navigation bar for my website. I want the navigation bar to stay fixed to the top whilst scrolling down. However, as the navbar only starts on the second page (the blue page), it should only show whilst scrolling down from the second page. Simply, the navbar should not appear whatsoever in the orange section.

I have tried adding this to `#firstpage .topnav` in the css. Whilst this does make the navbar stick to the top, it appears in the orange section. The navbar should only start on the second page:

```
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
```

Minimal Reproducible example:

```css
#about {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
  
#frontslider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: orange;
}
    
    
#frontslider p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 80px;
  color: #dfba57;
  font-size: 30px;
}


#firstpage .topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

#firstpage .topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#firstpage .topnav a:hover {
  color: #d7b916;
}
    
#firstpage .topnav a.active {
  color: #d7b916;
}

#services {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <section id="frontslider">
    <p>MY WEBSITE</p>
  </section>


  <section id="firstpage">
    <div class="topnav d-flex justify-content-center">
      <a class="active" href="#about">ABOUT US</a>
      <a href="#services">SERVICES</a>
      <a href="#portfolio">GALLERY</a>
      <a href="#team">LOCATION</a>
      <a href="#faq">FAQ</a>
      <a href="#contact">CONTACT US</a>
    </div>
  </section>


  <section id="about">

  </section>


  <section id="services">

  </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CSS-only solution!

This page may be helpful: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp.

You can use `position: sticky` on the navbar and pull it out of the firstpage section, into a parent div containing all the other sections.

https://jsfiddle.net/e4k8rjx9/12/

```css
#about {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
  
#frontslider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: orange;
}
    
    
#frontslider p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 80px;
  color: #dfba57;
  font-size: 30px;
}


#pages .topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#pages .topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#pages .topnav a:hover {
  color: #d7b916;
}
    
#pages .topnav a.active {
  color: #d7b916;
}

#services {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <section id="frontslider">
    <p>MY WEBSITE</p>
  </section>

  <div id="pages">
    <div class="topnav d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a class="active" href="#about">ABOUT US</a>
        <a href="#services">SERVICES</a>
        <a href="#portfolio">GALLERY</a>
        <a href="#team">LOCATION</a>
        <a href="#faq">FAQ</a>
        <a href="#contact">CONTACT US</a>
    </div>
    <section id="firstpage">
    
    </section>


    <section id="about">

    </section>


    <section id="services">

    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Story Time</title>
    <style>
      #about {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      #frontslider {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: orange;
      }

      #frontslider p {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 80px;
        color: #dfba57;
        font-size: 30px;
      }

      #firstpage .topnav {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: white;
      }

      #firstpage .topnav a {
        float: left;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 25px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 500;
      }

      #firstpage .topnav a:hover {
        color: #d7b916;
      }

      #firstpage .topnav a.active {
        color: #d7b916;
      }

      #services {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: green;
      }
      .fixed {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section id="frontslider">
      <p>MY WEBSITE</p>
    </section>

    <section id="firstpage">
      <div class="topnav d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a class="active" href="#about">ABOUT US</a>
        <a href="#services">SERVICES</a>
        <a href="#portfolio">GALLERY</a>
        <a href="#team">LOCATION</a>
        <a href="#faq">FAQ</a>
        <a href="#contact">CONTACT US</a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="about"></section>

    <section id="services"></section>

    <script>
      let header = document.querySelector(".topnav");
      let storData = header.offsetTop;
      window.addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {
        if (window.scrollY >= storData) {
          header.classList.add("fixed");
        } else {
          header.classList.remove("fixed");
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the scroll event, and when the window offset is greater than the topnav element's topOffset, you need to make it fixed. And remove it when it is less.

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollHandler()};

var topnav= document.getElementById("topnav");
var topNavOffset= topnav.offsetTop;

function scrollHandler() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= topNavOffset) {
    topnav.classList.add("fixed")
  } else {
    topnav.classList.remove("fixed");
  }
}
```

and for the fixed css class, you need to set the top and width, since the element is being made fixed element to make sure it sits on the top and fills the full width.

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```